# How to test class which implements Runnable with Junit

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

I have a class implements Runnable like this

```
  public Processor implements Runnable{

  public void run() {
     while (true) {
     //some code
     sendRequest(object);
      }
   }
}

 public void sendRequest(Object, object){
 // do something to send the event
  }
}
```

And in other pre-load class. I use

```
Processor processor = new Processor();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executor.execute(processor)
```

So my question is how can I unit test sendRequest method is called or not?

Comment: To where does sendRequest send something? It isn't clear from the example. Generally I would inject/obtain a mocked destination  that can report the success/failure to the test class, with an appropriate timeout. To a certain extent, it is akin to how greenmail supports mail testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate the concerns : the `Runnable` and the logic associated.
It will make in addition your code mode testable.
You could extract `sendRequest()` in a `Foo` class that the `Processor` class depends on. 
Then you have just to mock this `Foo` class in your test and verify that the `sendRequest()` method was invoked.

For example :

```
 public Processor implements Runnable{

  private Foo foo;

  public Processor(Foo foo){
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public void run() {
     while (true) {
       //some code
       foo.sendRequest(object);
     }
   }
}
```

And the test :

```
@Mock
Foo fooMock;

@Test
public void run() {
    Processor processor = new Processor(fooMock);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.execute(processor);
    executor.awaitTermination(someTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Mockito.verify(fooMock).sendRequest(...);   
}
```

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same thing. It's much better to have `run()` just delegate out to a method so it's easier to test without the Runnable making it more complex. It won't get you 100% coverage but it's a worthwhile trade-off

Comment: @Jimmy  Indeed complex untestable classes is really annoying. And using PowerMock or partial mocking is personally a no way. But why do you think that the coverage could be hurt by such a refactoring ?

Comment: @ davidxxx So I have to extract the sendRequest method to another class for unit testing?

Comment: Exactly. A sane refactoring.

Comment: We should shutdown executorService. 
 executor.execute(processor);                                                                                                                                       
 executor.shutdown);                                                                                                                                                   
 executor.awaitTermination(someTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 3):

i believe you want to test only implemented `run()` method, so you can call the method directly using `Processor` object or you can create a thread and pass runnable object to it and call `Thread.start()`

If `sendRequest(Object object)` method is doing any external operations i will suggest you to mock that method

```
public class ThreadTest {

@Test(//throws some exception)
public void shouldThrowSomeException() {
    Processor exThread = new Processor ();
    exThread.run(); //or
    Thread t = new Thread(exThread);
     t.start()

    }
}
```

**Mocking** for mocking [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions)

```
@Test(//throws some exception)
public void shouldThrowSomeException() {
    Processor exThreadmock = mock(Processor.class);
    when(exThreadmock.sendRequest(anyObject))
    .thenThrow(SomeException.class)
    Thread t = new Thread(exThread);
     t.start()

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mockito.spy` for partial mocking.

```
Processor processor = spy(new Processor());

doCallRealMethod().when(processor).run();

verify(processor).sendRequest(mock1, mock2);
```

Comment: I follow your steps but the sendRequest method is not invoked